# how to add extra element in laravel collection

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-collection

i would like to know how can i add extra column in laravel collection, return from database. for instance.

User Model 
User->id
User->name

Reservation Model
Reservation->user_id
Reservation->id

now

```
$users = User::all();
$user_reservation = Reservation::all();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        foreach ($user_reservation as $ur) 
        {
            if ($user->id == $ur->user_id) 
            {
            //Add extra column in to the users model
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a something called $appends with Accessors. how to use it

Define $append in the model where you want to add custom collection. in my case User model

```
    class User extends Model{

    protected $appends = ['user_eservation'];

    public function getUserReservations($id)
    {
        return User::where('id', $id)->first();
    }

    public function getUserReservationAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getUserReservations(Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

and now you can call the custom attribute which is not available in the database , by calling the getUserReservatoin function.

for instance

$users = User::all();
$user_reservation = Reservation::all();

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    foreach ($user_reservation as $ur) 
    {
        if ($user->id == $ur->user_id) 
        {
        $user->getUserReservations();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->push(['extra_column' => $value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only declare new public property of the model (but not new field in the table).

```
    class User extends Model{
          public reservation;
```

than you can set this property for any users collection item.